# Add custom formatter tags in papertrail Logger in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-logging

settings Page:

```
"formatters": {
        "simple": {
            "format": "%(name)s %(asctime)s %(message)s",
            "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S",
        },
    },
```

If  I write here code like this:

```
"formatters": {
            "simple": {
                "format": "%(name)s %(ip)s %(user)s %(client)s %(asctime)s %(message)s",
                "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S",
            },
        },
```

It is showing following Error:

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python10\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 440, in format
    return self._format(record)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python10\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 436, in _format
    return self._fmt % values
KeyError: 'ip'
```

Answer (score 0):

`ip` is not one of the available parameters: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes

Comment: Yes, but how to add custom parameters in the settings section only. Docs don't mention this.

Comment: You don't have a specific request object in settings, so the best you can do is something like: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#context-info

Answer (score 0):

You can provide extra keys for your logger in views, like this:

```
def send_log(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    extra = {
        "ip": visitor_ip_address(request),
        "username": request.user.username,
        "role": request.user.role,

    }

    logger.info('foo bar', extra=extra)
```